# Xcode: This method is missing a correct divider before it

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

```
- (void)setDelegate:(id<MyDelegate>)delegate {
  _delegate = delegate;

  if (_delegate) {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =
    [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Close"
                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                     target:self
                                     action:@selector(closeView)] autorelease];
  }
}

- (void)closeView {
    [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:NO];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
}
```

The line "- (void)closeView {" is marked yellow in XCode 4 and the warning is: "This method is missing a correct divider before it".

What does this warning means?

Comment: Please show the code directly above this code in your file

Comment: I edit my question and add more code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add "//////////////////" in the line before the method!

```
///////////////////////////////////////
- (void)closeView {
}
```

My code is inside "TTThumbsViewController" of the framework Three20. Before every method are these slashes:
https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20UI/Sources/TTThumbsViewController.m

Comment: This seems to be some kind of syntax checker in Three20 to make sure each method has those slashes before it. If you add them it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change that method to

```
- (void)closeView:(id)sender{
```

Comment: You are correct with your code, but unfortunately there's still the same warning.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode does not see a proper "divider" meaning (probably) that the white space is something else than the required newline.  Delete and re-type the code including the closing curly braces through the method starting line.

Or examine the lines in another editor that has a mode to show all the characters such as TextWrangler (free from Bare Bones Software).